# Create attributes from CSV as a loop

Tags: php, magento, while-loop

I am writing a script to create Magento attributes programatically, pulling the data from a CSV. Not sure I have the actual loop correct that pulls the data from the CSV - was hoping for some expert guidance on the logic?

```
    <?php 
$fh = fopen("attributes.csv", "r");
$i = 0;
while (($l = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $i++;
    if($i == 1) continue; //ignoring the headers, so skip row 0
    $data['label'] = trim($l[2]);
    $data['input'] = trim($l[3]);
    $data['type'] = trim($l[2]);

    //Create the attribute

    $data=array(
'type'=>$data['type'],
'input'=>'text',
'label'=>$data['label'],
'global'=>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
'is_required'=>'0',
'is_comparable'=>'0',
'is_searchable'=>'0',
'is_unique'=>'1',
'is_configurable'=>'1',
'use_defined'=>'1'
);

$model->addAttribute('catalog_product','test_attribute',$data);

}   

?>
```

I basically just want it to grab the attribute data from the CSV, and for each row in the CSV run the code to create it (using the label and name as specified in the CSV - im guessing I am missing something obvious in the loop? (just really learning what I'm doing!)

Comment: What happens when you run this script? Also, look on this article http://alanstorm.com/magento_attribute_migration_generator, it should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reset the `$data` array in each loop, after inserting the values from CSV, so the CSV-content gets lost. Try this

```
$fh = fopen("attributes.csv", "r");
$i = 0;
$attributes=array(); //!!
while (($l = fgetcsv($fh, 1024, ",")) !== FALSE) {

    $i++;
    if($i == 1) continue; //ignoring the headers, so skip row 0

    $data=array();

    $data['label'] = trim($l[2]);
    $data['input'] = trim($l[3]);
    $data['type'] = trim($l[2]);

    $data['global']=Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL;
    $data['is_required']='0';
    $data['is_comparable']='0';
    $data['is_searchable']='0';
    $data['is_unique']='1';
    $data['is_configurable']='1';
    $data['use_defined']='1';

    //insert $data to the attributes array
    $attributes[]=$data;
    //or
    $model->addAttribute('catalog_product','test_attribute',$data);
}
```